# How to "invalidate" shadowPath on view layer in cell?

Tags: ios, swift

I have UIView with layer.shadowPath property in UICollectionViewCell/UITableViewCell.
By device rotation, the width of the cell  changes, but shadowPath remains the same. How to "redraw" the shadow in this case? .reloadData() does not help.
Swift.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the custom class of you cell, set the path in layout subviews. The method is automatically called every time a layout change is made, such as orientation change.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
   super.layoutSubviews()

   yourLayer.shadowPath = yourPath
}
```